# Show woocommerce product after gravity form submission

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

the below code will print the products which fall under the same category, that is, $field_two will contain the category.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'access_entry_via_field', 10, 2 );

function access_entry_via_field( $entry, $form ) {

    $field_one = $_POST['input_1'];
    $field_two = $_POST['input_6'];

    $items = array("age"=>"$field_one", "skin_type"=>"$field_two");

    $args = array(
        "category" => array("$field_two"),
    );

    $products = wc_get_products($args);

    var_dump($products); exit();

}
```

Once the gravity form is submitted, How to show the products ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this you have to change your confirmation message of the form where you get the values of the entries to use them after to filter the results

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_1', 'custom_confirmation_message', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation_message( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {
   $field_one = $entry["1.1"];
   $field_two = $entry["1.6"];

   $items = array("age"=>"$field_one", "skin_type"=>"$field_two");

   $args = array(
       "category" => array("$field_two"),
    );
    $products = wc_get_products($args);

    $confirmation .= 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.';
    $confirmation .= $products;

return $confirmation;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.Array

Comment: That means the code is working but the issue is with the products query that depends on what you have ....please try to replace with a more general query that will show last 10 products for example: $args = array(
    'limit' => 10,
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

Answer (score 1):

Try this filter. `gform_confirmation` instead of `gform_after_submission`.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation/

**Update**: To show woocommerce products on confirmation page use this (just replace numbers with product ID's):

```
echo do_shortcode('[products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"]');
```

Comment: using your answer i am able to redirect to the respective products page, but what i wanted is to show products in the same page once the gravity form is submitted.